# Tomcat6 ignores web-inf/lib

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, classloader, web-inf

**Brief:** Tomcat6 can't recognize my ojdbc14.jar in WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib. I suppose I don't need to configure anything, just putting the .jar file in there and it should work.

**Details:**

I've created a web application and put ojdbc14.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder.  When I start Tomcat6 and **access an index.jsp page which creates an object that initiates a connection to my oracle database**, an error occurs saying "Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'".  Apparently **Tomcat6 can't recognize the 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' class in web-inf/lib/ojdbc14.jar**.

I've done some research and speculate the following reasons:

1. Tomcat6 has got some different ways of loading classes.  They change it in every version released. Or
2. There is a bug with Tomcat6.  I found a similar bug in Tomcat3 (see here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249044).  But I doubt this bug could last for so many versions.
3. Tomcat6 has included ojdbc14.jar's content in its own lib file already, and there's a conflict by adding it to web-inf/lib once more.  I don't believe this, because after deleting ojdbc14.jar from WEB-INF/lib, the problem persists.

Here's my web application structure:

- WebRoot

  - WEB-INF

    - classes

      - 'A class for initiating a connection'
    - lib

      - ojdbc14.jar
  - index.jsp

---

The error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
    at com.demo6.DataSourceExample.getConnection(DataSourceExample.java:18)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:216)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:760)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: The way I load the class is by calling 'Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");'

Answer (score 10):

The stacktrace tells that you've created a `DataSource` as `<Resource>` in Tomcat's side. In that case, the JDBC driver JAR file really needs to be put in Tomcat's side as well as it's Tomcat who manages the `DataSource`, not your webapp. Drop it in `Tomcat/lib` and this exception should disappear. You could also drop it in an external folder and add its path  to Tomcat's common classpath as definied by `common.loader` property in `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

Please note that you don't need to load the driver manually. Just grab the `DataSource` and then get the `Connection` from it.

Comment: Yes, it worked.  But I'm after a more general question: why can't Tomcat6 recognize my .jar file in WEB-INF/lib?  It's not just the ojdbc.jar, but any .jar at all.  After all, putting every .jar file in Tomcat/lib is not always a good idea.

Comment: That just because Tomcat manages the datasource, not the webapp. The `/WEB-INF/lib` is exclusively to the webapp itself. I did not said that you should put every JAR there in `Tomcat/lib`, just the JARs it *needs*.