# ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I know there are thousands of blogs about CNFEs out there, but I can't get it work.

I use Maven to build my GWT project. In the pom.xml, there is this line:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the built .war file, there is the correct .jar in WEB-INF/lib. So the class is where I expect it to be. But I'm still getting a ClassNotFoundException.

Where am I wrong? Is it because of the runtime scope?

Comment: well, does it work if you remove the scope? have you updated your maven dependencies?

Comment: When do you receive the exception? If it comes during the build then it is surly because of the runtime scope.

Comment: The exception is thrown on runtime when I want to access the db.

Comment: Also not working without runtime scope

Comment: Perhaps you have other versions as well? (other jars, included differently maybe)

Comment: I have 2 environments where the webapp runs. I found out, that it works on the one environment, but not on the other one. So it´s most likely a platform specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project build-path and enable specific output folders for each folder. Go one by one through each source-folder of your project and set the output folder that Maven would use.

For eg., your web project's `src/main/java` should have `target/classes` under the web project and so.

If your web project require some configuration files that are under the resources, be sure to include that folder as a source folder and to make the proper build-path configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that the driver needs to be inside tomcat´s /lib folder.

It has something to do with the DataSource as described in this post:

[Tomcat6 ignores web-inf/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222733/tomcat6-ignores-web-inf-lib/7222794)